# Navigation looks wrong when it's fixed

Tags: html, css, navigation, fixed

I want the position of my navigation to be fixed. But when I change the position to "fixed" in nav, it looks very weird.
Here are two examples:
Without fixed position: https://jsfiddle.net/Timowo/3nrvch3c/

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li class="category active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="logotext">Logo</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

With fixed position: https://jsfiddle.net/Timowo/5aock5k1/

```
    <nav style="position: fixed;">
  <ul>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li class="category active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="logotext">Logo</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

What do I have to change so it's inline but also fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `position:fixed` the element will collapse to the width of the widest descendant..in the absence of a defined width.

Just set `width:100%`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}
nav ul li.logo {
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
}
nav ul li.logotext {
  font-family: Futura;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 28px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}
nav ul li.category a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  float: right;
  font-family: Futura;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}
nav ul li.category:hover a {
  background-color: #212121;
}
nav ul li.active a {
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category"><a href="#">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category active"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="logotext">Logo</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```